# Двоеточие или тире в БСП

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, бсп, тире-или-двоеточие

Скажите, пожалуйста, уместно ли в этих двух предложениях тире? Ведь можно между частями поставить "а именно", значит, должно быть двоеточие?

Мы знали, что делать – как организовать штаб, наладить его работу.

Но счастье длилось недолго – проработали так всего три или четыре месяца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постановка знаков во многом зависит **от контекста**, поэтому решать задачу для отдельного предложения мы всегда можем с определенной условностью.

Мы знаем, что двоеточие является **основным (классическим)** знаком, если вторая часть раскрывает, поясняет содержание первой. Но также нам известно, что тире **может заменять** двоеточие (при этом меняется расстановка ударений, выражаются **разные оттенки** значений).

1. ***Мы знали, что дЕлать**: как организовать штаб, наладить его работу.*

Имеется в виду: что именно делать. Здесь более уместным выглядит **двоеточие**, если ударение падает на глагол "**делать**". Двоеточие обозначает **интонационное предупреждение** о дальнейшем раскрытии темы (неполное понижение голоса перед длительной паузой).

***Мы знАли, что делать** — как организовать штаб, наладить его работу.*

При постановке **тире** вторая часть имеет **присоединительный характер,** главная мысль выражена в первой части (ударением выделен глагол "знали").

2. ***Но счастье длилось недолго** — проработали так всего три или четыре месяца.*

В этом предложении, наоборот, более убедительно выглядит **тире**, хотя двоеточие тоже не исключается.

**А смысл** примерно такой же: при постановке **тире** главное сказано в первой части, а второе сообщение оформлено как **присоединительное**. Пауза в этом случае меньшей длительности, чем при двоеточии.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138178/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-----).

Comment: А к чему здесь грамматика? На что она здесь влияет? Приведите конкретный пример. Разве что то, что у Розенталя такого типа присоединение в теме о простом предложении.

Comment: Можно вмешаться? Не понимаю, что вы здесь обсуждаете? Второе предложение – БСП, возможны все три знака, но запятая не очень подходит. Выбирайте тире или двоеточие по вкусу – это вариативно.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец
Полностью с вами согласна (по второму предложению).  Там первое предложение требует внимания. СПП с тремя однородными придаточными, а однородны они только по грамматике, но не по семантике. Знак (тире или двоеточие) делит предложение на два блока. Как вам это нравится, Розенталь рассматривал такие конструкции?

Comment: @oleedd  Вы меня своим вспомогательным комментарием разочаровали вконец. Найдите вот эту книгу и хотя бы посмотрите на нее, уже польза будет https://dic.academic.ru/book.nsf/62187173/Толковый+словарь+словообразовательных+единиц+русского+языка

Comment: Нет, не нужно мне словообразование, если о слове никто не знает, то его нет. При однородных придаточных ставится запятая! Сколько союзов, столько и придаточных!

Comment: "Мы знали, что делать - как организовать штаб, наладить его работу".  Это вот здесь у вас запятая ставится?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Сначала спорили о том, что тире во втором примере интонационное, так как нет у Розенталя подходящего пункта. А теперь уже и о других вещах. Но первое всё же важнее.

Comment: Это вы сами с собою спорили. Сделайте грамматический разбор предложения: Мы знали, что делать - как организовать штаб, наладить его работу"

Comment: Хотя нет, не спорили. У вас не было ничего, чтобы возразить. Но вы же говорите о трёх однородных придаточных! Там их два, но пусть уже будет три. При однородных придаточных ставится запятая. Почитайте Розенталя. Вывод: нет там однородных придаточных, они просто согласованы! Вот однородные придаточные: *Мы знали: что делать, как организовать штаб, как наладить его работу.* А когда одно придаточное исходит из другого, какая уже может быть однородность?

Comment: Однородность — это когда элементы **одинаково** к чему-либо относятся, когда они отвечают на **один и тот же вопрос** (про это уже все слышали). Но не когда вопрос задаётся от одного придаточного к другому.

Comment: Достало уже это всё! Крик души! Учите матчасть.

Comment: oleedd, а зачем вы все это объясняете мне, нервы тратите? Почему бы вам не дать альтернативный ответ – простейшее решение. мы не слышим друг друга, так к чему разговор? Например: "Но не когда вопрос задаётся от одного придаточного к другому". О чем это вы?  Какой вопрос? У нас есть последовательное подчинение придаточных, но это  не наш случай. Нам попалась нестандартная грамматика. Но вы не можете это понять, не знаете, что с ней делать. Так что сами учите матчасть, ага7

Comment: Я всё равно не понимаю, о чём вы спорите. @oleedd, у Розенталя почти все пункты о БСП подходят  ко второму предложению для двоеточия или тире. Какая разница, присоединение ли, следствие, причина, пояснение – если ставим тире, то оно будет, да, интонационным по своей сути (разделяющим две части), но не тем термином, о котором говорится в соответствующем разделе. // Первое предложение тоже не замысловатое, только лучше, на мой взгляд, звучало бы с союзом:     *как организовать штаб **и** наладить его работу*. Вы-то, oleedd, какие препинания видите?

Comment: Если у Розенталя нет идентичных конструкций и примеров – не беда. :) Мы же на тирях и двуеточках собаку съели! Свободу!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец *то оно будет, да, интонационным по своей сути* — вот, это и пытался доказать, потому что Sharon начала резко высказываться против этого и хотела объяснений. На самом деле правильное отнесение к пунктам здесь очень важно, очень круто понимать, почему тот или иной пункт работает, тогда правильно обращаться с этими знаками — легко. Там одни и те же причины крутятся, если разобраться (можно сделать меньше пунктов, чем у Розенталя).

Comment: @Sharon *Но вы не можете это понять, не знаете, что с ней делать* — к чему эти обвинения? Это вода, а не по факту. Пока только вы не понимаете, всё переспрашиваете... "*Как организовать штаб, наладить его работу*" относится к глаголу "делать", оно поясняет его (но не так, как у Розенталя, вообще уже не хочу рассказывать о таких сложных моментах), можно, допустим, задать вопрос "*что именно делать?*".

Comment: oleedd, вы разобрались с грамматикой? Тогда ответьте на мой вопрос. Только четко, как это принято в школе. В комментариях я вас три раза об этом просила.  Только один разбор по обычной схеме, пока без знаков и без Розенталя.

Comment: @oleedd  Я вот о чем. Просто в **терминологическом** плане тире называется **интонационным** в других ситуациях, в другом разделе, где рассматриваются неочевидные случаи его постановки, между теми словами или группами слов, когда делается выбор: нужно это интонационное подчеркивание или нет. А в БСП тире становится обязательным знаком, его здесь уже не называют интонационным, хотя всем понятно, что любой знак **по своей сути** призван отражать интонацию.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец В этом параграфе чуть-чуть каша. В примерах пункта, в котором говорится про неожиданность, в основном тоже интонационное тире. Ведь неожиданность — это как раз про такое тире, его чаще всего ставят по этой причине. Хотя, может быть, Розенталь хотел включить интонационное тире в параграф о БСП, ему необходимо было указать все причины. Ну назовите пункт (только не про неожиданность), раз уж тире обязательно, Sharon не смогла.

Comment: @Sharon Давайте чёткие вопросы по пунктам. Чёткие ответы даются лишь на чёткие вопросы.

Comment: Хорош уже меня склонять: не знает, не разбирается, не смогла. Прочитайте заданный вопрос. Там-то что вам неясно? Сделайте грамматический разбор предложения по школьным правилам. давайте с этого начнем.

Comment: @oleedd Для двоеточия: во второй части заключается пояснение, раскрывается содержание первой части (между частями можно вставить слова *а именно*) – § 44, пункт 1. Для тире немного сложнее, больше всего подходит пункт 9, § 45: вторая часть представляет собой присоединительное предложение. Но это всё неважно. Выбор у нас невелик, а параграф [Двоеточие — тире](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=189) даёт свободу: "Вариативны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с пояснительными отношениями."

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Вот, спасибо вам за пункт 9, вы мне помогаете объяснить. Как раз здесь дело в подстановке слова "это", хорошо, что Розенталь о нём тоже сказал. *Но счастье длилось недолго – [это] три или четыре месяца. Но счастье длилось недолго – [это] проработали так всего три или четыре месяца.* Во втором случае определительные отношения поломаны, поэтому тире интонационное. По поводу раскрытия содержания: там не должно быть родового слова, как в нашем случае, должно быть повествование.

Comment: @oleedd При чём здесь родовое слово? И где об этом сказано (если уж для всего нужен пункт)? Я уже писал выше: выбирайте знак по вкусу, их всего два-три. Больше не хочу на эту тему.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Просто в первом примере на первый план выходит перечисление (с родовым словом), нежели раскрытие содержания. Но здесь даже сложнее объяснить. Просто раскрытие содержания не так работает. Там должно быть грамматически независимое повествование.