# Грамматический разбор нестандартного предложения

Tags: грамматика, синтаксический-разбор, тире-или-двоеточие

***Мы знали, что делать – как организовать штаб, как наладить его работу.***

Это предложение из недавней темы (добавлен второй союз КАК) [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471820/Двоеточие-или-тире-в-БСП](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471820/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%A1%D0%9F)

Интонационно здесь подходит **тире или двоеточие**, но какова грамматика предложения?

**Вариант 1.** Это СПП с тремя однородными изъяснительными придаточными: *Мы знали, что делать, как организовать штаб, как наладить его работу.*

Но однородны они только **по грамматике, а не по смыслу**, так как первое придаточное является **обобщающим** по отношению к двум другим.

Тогда приходится делить предложение на **два смысловых блока** и знак (тире или двоеточие) ставить между ними. О смысловых блоках говорится в ПАС  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136

В этом случае знак между блоками мы выбираем сами **(тире или двоеточие).**

**Вариант 2.** Считать вторую часть **присоединительной конструкцией** и поставить тире: **Мы знали, что делать – как организовать штаб, как наладить его работу.** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Но присоединительные члены предложения обычно содержат **дополнительные разъяснения или замечания**, по семантике такой разбор не очень подходит. К тому же в этом случае двоеточие не ставится, **только тире.**

**Вопросы:**

1. Как сделать грамматический разбор предложения?
2. Как применить к этому предложению правила Розенталя или ПАС?

Спасибо.

**Примечание.** Чтобы вопрос **не казался праздным** и отвлеченным от практики письма, я еще раз напомню. От грамматического разбора зависит **выбор знаков препинания:** (1) двоеточие или тире; (2) только тире.

Comment: Почему у вас каждый глагол "открывает" простое предложение? У вас так и с безличными предложениями было. Вспомните правила о СПП, **придаточное предложение присоединяется подчинительным союзом**. Нет союза — нет и придаточного.

Comment: Присоединительные конструкции спокойно присоединяются за счёт запятой. Откуда у тире такая монополия?

Comment: Лично для вас поставила второй союз КАК.  Теперь все ОК, можете приступать к разбору.

Comment: Не увлекаюсь синтаксисом: это вещь почти бесполезная.

Comment: Забавно. Все правила Розенталя основаны на  безупречном знании грамматики, а синтаксис – это часть грамматики, где изучается грамматический строй предложения. Можно считать себя специалистом по пунктуации и при этом не увлекаться грамматикой?

Comment: На безупречном? Это перебор. Для их применения порой требуется умение определить количество грамматических основ и сказуемое. Что ещё нужно и зачем?

Comment: Здесь даже этого не нужно, все уже разобрано. Сделайте выбор только из двух вариантов:  (1) Это СПП с тремя придаточными и делением на два смысловых блока. (2) Это СПП с одним придаточным и присоединительной конструкцией.  Но если варианты вас не устраивают, то делайте полный разбор "по процедуре":  грамматическая основа и все прочее.

Comment: (1) А разве такое бывает? Где у Розенталя такое? (2) Норм.

Comment: (1)  Смысловые блоки есть в ПАС. И что вы прилипли к Розенталю, дайте ему отдохнуть. Если (2) двоеточие нельзя ставить, а это сомнительно.

Comment: (1) Какой параграф? У нас здесь тире между придаточными. Если блок, то вы просто подчёркиваете сказанное далее и оно относится к главному: *Мы знали, что делать — [**и**] как организовать штаб, наладить его работу.* (2) Двоеточие можно, если перечисление, но два элемента — это маловато.

Comment: 1. А кто вам разрешил ставить тире между придаточными?  Опять самодеятельность. 2. У Розенталя нет двоеточия в присоединительных конструкциях http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120 3. ПАС (про блоки)  http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136

Comment: 1. Мне никто не разрешал. Это же вы так хотите сделать. 2. Если перечисление, то уже не присоединительная. 3. Так то не те блоки, там в основном о точке с запятой.